# How to hide certain views from ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arccatalog, sql-view

I have users that connect to an enterprise geodatabase via OS authentication. They use a couple of methods:

1. An .SDE connection in ArcMap
2. A ODBC connection for MS Office

The users need to be able to connect to all of the views in the GDB using the ODBC connection.

However, the users only need to connect to some of the views in ArcMap. The rest of the views are not needed in ArcMap (they just create clutter--there are hundreds of them).

Is there a way to hide certain views from ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it used to be possible to register a table as "hidden" in the table registry, but doing so never actually removed tables from the table list. It hasn't been possible to register a table like this in so long that the last version to support it was retired earlier this month.

There is no way to prevent the "list tables" or "list layers" functions from listing any reasonably named view or table (that don't conflict with the reserved names for support tables).

Comment: I suspect that there must be some sort of blacklisting of system tables happening to prevent them from being shown in Catalog. If so, do you know if the blacklist is stored in the application or in the database?

Comment: It's just a WHERE clause, but it's in the connection DLLs (not suitable for modification)